# time count after registry

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I saw some website that after you have registered, you can use the service like posting a comment immediately.

You may have to wait for 5 or 10 minutes to be able to start, like this StackOverflow website.

Once you have asked question, you have to wait 20 minutes to select your answer.

If I want to do it in JavaScript or PHP can anyone show me how to do it? I assume you have to compare the time with current time-stamp, but don't know how to exactly implement it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a datetime string stored in a variable, you could do something like:

```
// TODO: get a datetime string into $time
$minutes = 5;
if (strtotime($time) + $minutes * 60 < time()) {
    // It's been 5 minutes since $time
}
```

Comment: in this sense there, but I think the date will be brought from the database, since the registration date, can be recorded in a session or cookie

Comment: Just a note, it's better to store a unixtime rather than a string. If you get it from a database do `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(column_name)`. Strings can give you issues with timezones, and are slower and larger.

Comment: @Ariel `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` does the same thing as `strtotime`

Comment: @rfausak That is not true. If you use the timestamp column of MySQL (and you should) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP will give you that timestamp without having to first convert to a date and time string and then back again in PHP. If you have a MySQL datetime datatype (and you should not) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP can directly work with the MySQL datatype without having to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
$wait_time = 10*60; //10 minutes * 60 seconds
if(time() > $start_time + $wait_time) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, you'll want to compare the date of posting, with the current date, but then formulate the conditions that will validate a new post or the selection of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Each question that is posted will require server side storage, if not exclusively in a db then there will need to be at least a record in a table linking the question to the user.

Once a question has been posted you could either have the server side script that loads the question carry out the following tasks.

- Get the question entry
- Is the person that posted the question the current requesting user 
  [yes]

  - Is the request time minus the post time greater than (number of mins * 60)
    [yes]
  - Include select answer buttons (html objects or buttons)

Alternatively you could always show the buttons and carry out the above logic and return some indication that the  user must wait x minutes before they can select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the creation time (of whatever object or saving) along with the item being created in the database.  So for example, if you create a question on SO, they probably store the time you posted the question.  Then when you go to view your question, they probably get the difference between the current time and the time stored.

So say that you want to implement a 20 minute wait after posting a question before you can select an answer.  Then you upload a question at 5:00 PM.  When you attempt to view your question at 5:05PM the same day, the difference in time is 5:05PM - 5:00PM, which is 5 minutes.  Take 20 minutes - 5 minutes to get the time the user must wait, and send that back to the page.

From javascript you can get that time limit (15min), and create a setTimeout method to "unlock" the answer feature.  The code would look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="waitfor" value="15">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var waitfor = $('#waitfor').val();

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        // let the user know they can post an answer
    }, waitfor * 60 * 1000);
});
```

Also, I'd let the user post an answer whenever they'd like, but prevent it being submitted on the client side if it hasn't been 20 minutes.